# split mail message with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split incoming mail messages into word array. smth like this:

`"Hi,.***Build,   son,!8loop"`

into

```
['Hi' , 'Build', 'son', 'loop']
```

i know you want to send me to learn it by myself but i've read alot of articles but still no ideas.

p.s. using regex+javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Replace all non-word characters by a white space:

   ```
   str = str.replace(/[\W\d\s]+/g, ' ');
   ```

   You might have to adjust this to your needs, to replace the right characters:

   - `\W` matches everything expect letters, digits, and underscores
   - `\d` matches digits
   - `\s` matches white spaces

   There are other ways to write an equivalent expression.
2. Then split bye white space:

   ```
   words = str.split(' ');
   ```

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a good website to learn about regular expressions. For regular expressions in JavaScript, have a look at the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).